# Kubernetes readiness probe warning has no details

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I've made a deployment in GKE with a readiness probe. My container is coming up but it seems the readiness probe is having some difficulty. When I try to describe the pod I see that there are many probe warnings but it's not clear what the warning is.

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                   Age                   From                     Message
  ----     ------                   ----                  ----                     -------
  Normal   Scheduled                43m                   default-scheduler        Successfully assigned default/tripvector-7996675758-7vjxf to gke-tripvector2-default-pool-78cf58d9-5dgs
  Normal   LoadBalancerNegNotReady  43m                   neg-readiness-reflector  Waiting for pod to become healthy in at least one of the NEG(s): [k8s1-07274a01-default-tripvector-np-60000-a912870e]
  Normal   Pulling                  43m                   kubelet                  Pulling image "us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/triptastic-1542412229773/tripvector/tripvector"
  Normal   Pulled                   43m                   kubelet                  Successfully pulled image "us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/triptastic-1542412229773/tripvector/tripvector" in 888.583654ms
  Normal   Created                  43m                   kubelet                  Created container tripvector
  Normal   Started                  43m                   kubelet                  Started container tripvector
  Normal   LoadBalancerNegTimeout   32m                   neg-readiness-reflector  Timeout waiting for pod to become healthy in at least one of the NEG(s): [k8s1-07274a01-default-tripvector-np-60000-a912870e]. Marking condition "cloud.google.com/load-balancer-neg-ready" to True.
  Warning  ProbeWarning             3m1s (x238 over 42m)  kubelet                  Readiness probe warning:
```

I've tried examining events with `kubectl get events` but that also doesn't provide extra details on the probe warning:

```
 ❯❯❯ k get events
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON                    OBJECT                             MESSAGE
43m         Normal    LoadBalancerNegNotReady   pod/tripvector-7996675758-7vjxf    Waiting for pod to become healthy in at least one of the NEG(s): [k8s1-07274a01-default-tripvector-np-60000-a912870e]
43m         Normal    Scheduled                 pod/tripvector-7996675758-7vjxf    Successfully assigned default/tripvector-7996675758-7vjxf to gke-tripvector2-default-pool-78cf58d9-5dgs
43m         Normal    Pulling                   pod/tripvector-7996675758-7vjxf    Pulling image "us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/triptastic-1542412229773/tripvector/tripvector"
43m         Normal    Pulled                    pod/tripvector-7996675758-7vjxf    Successfully pulled image "us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/triptastic-1542412229773/tripvector/tripvector" in 888.583654ms
43m         Normal    Created                   pod/tripvector-7996675758-7vjxf    Created container tripvector
43m         Normal    Started                   pod/tripvector-7996675758-7vjxf    Started container tripvector
3m38s       Warning   ProbeWarning              pod/tripvector-7996675758-7vjxf    Readiness probe warning:
```

How can I get more details on how/why this readiness probe is giving off warnings?

EDIT: the logs of the pod are mostly empty as well (`klf` is an alias I have to kubectl logs):

```
 ❯❯❯ klf tripvector-6f4d4c86c5-dn55c
(node:1) [DEP0131] DeprecationWarning: The legacy HTTP parser is deprecated.
{"line":"87","file":"percolate_synced-cron.js","message":"SyncedCron: Scheduled \"Refetch expired Google Places\" next run @Tue Mar 22 2022 17:47:53 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)","time":{"$date":1647971273653},"level":"info"}
```

Comment: what did the `kubectl log <podname>` show ?

Comment: The logs are more or less empty. I'll update the post with the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the error in the logs ***“DeprecationWarning: The legacy HTTP parser is deprecated.”***, it is due to the legacy HTTP parser being deprecated with the pending ***End-of-Life of Node.js 10.x***. It will now warn on use, but otherwise continue to function and may be removed in a future **Node.js 12.x** release. Use this URL for more reference [Node v12.22.0 (LTS)](https://nodejs.org/ja/blog/release/v12.22.0/#:%7E:text=The%20legacy%20HTTP%20parser%20is%20runtime%20deprecated&text=x%20).

On the other hand, about the `kubelet`’s ***“ProbeWarning”*** reason in the warning events on your container, ***Health check (liveness & readiness)*** probes using an ***HTTPGetAction*** will no longer follow redirects to different host-names from the original probe request. Instead, these non-local redirects will be treated as a ***Success*** (the documented behavior). In this case an event with reason **"ProbeWarning"** will be generated, indicating that the redirect was ignored. If you were previously relying on the redirect to run health checks against different endpoints, you will need to perform the healthcheck logic outside the ***Kubelet***, for instance by proxying the external endpoint rather than redirecting to it. You can verify the detailed root cause of this in the following [Kubernetes 1.14 release notes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.14.md#urgent-upgrade-notes). There is no way to see more detailed information about the  **“ProbeWarning”** in the ***Events’*** table. Use the following URLs as a reference too [Kubernetes emitting ProbeWarning](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T294072), [Confusing/incomplete readiness probe warning](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/103877) and [Add probe warning message body](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/103967).

Comment: ah interesting, I don't think I have any redirects set up in my application. The `/heatlhz` endpoint I exposed directly by the server.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if this could be an issue with https. I currently have the app deployed on heroku and when I execute `curl http://app.tripvector.io/healthz` I get an empty response but when I execute `curl https://app.tripvector.io/healthz` (with https) I get the full response. I wonder if that is affecting how the healthcheck works on k8s?

Comment: and I see something similar when I run the app through docker locally. If I build a production image, and run the container with `-p 3000:3000`, none of the `curl` requests to `localhost:3000/healthz` get the full response object

Comment: Ah yup, my application has `force-ssl` installed which is probably why this is breaking. However, when I change my readiness probe to use HTTPS as the scheme, it has it's connection refused. That's probably some quirk of the package with kubernetes.

Comment: Another option you can try is the command `kubectl describe pod liveness-exec`, please do, use this [URL](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-command) as a deeper reference, and let us know the result. Regarding **https** theory, yes, that may affect the way **Healthcheck** behaves, or if you have **HTTPGetAction** set up, do you have it?